# Inserting A Button That Allows Me To Delete All SQLite Table Information on Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, button

Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k3CunDZpFk

I have successfully been able too get information's from SQLite Database and display in List View.

However, i do not know how to make a button that delete's this information when inserted, and where this code should go.

Would appreciate it if anybody could help.

Here is my dboperations.java
public class DbOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "standing_info.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "standing_table";
private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "create table "+StandingContract.StandingEntry.TABLE_NAME+
        "("+ StandingContract.StandingEntry.ID+ " text,"+ StandingContract.StandingEntry.WON+" text,"+
        StandingContract.StandingEntry.HALVED+ " text,"+ StandingContract.StandingEntry.LOST+" text,"+
        StandingContract.StandingEntry.POINTS+ " text);";

DbOperations(Context ctx) {

    super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Database created...");
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);

    Log.d("Database operations", "Table created...");

}

public void addInformations ( SQLiteDatabase db,String id,String won, String halved, String lost, String points){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(StandingContract.StandingEntry.ID,id);
    contentValues.put(StandingContract.StandingEntry.WON,won);
    contentValues.put(StandingContract.StandingEntry.HALVED,halved);
    contentValues.put(StandingContract.StandingEntry.LOST,lost);
    contentValues.put(StandingContract.StandingEntry.POINTS,points);
    db.insert(StandingContract.StandingEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    Log.d("Database operations", "One Row Inserted...");

}

public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase db)
{

    String[] projections = {StandingContract.StandingEntry.ID, StandingContract.StandingEntry.WON,
    StandingContract.StandingEntry.HALVED, StandingContract.StandingEntry.LOST, StandingContract.StandingEntry.POINTS};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(StandingContract.StandingEntry.TABLE_NAME,projections,

            null,null,null,null,null,null);

    return cursor;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Comment: Please describe the scenario .. rather than giving link on youtube

Comment: Here is what i tried   Delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {

                                      }

                                      public void DeleteDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, String table) {


                                          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "standing_table");
                                          db.close();
                                      }

            });

Comment: My main question is if i am adding a button to delete the sqlite table i have made do i need to use anything other than the xml where my button is located and my MainActivity.java.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Share your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity

```
DatabaseAdapter.DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseAdapter.DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      db.deleteAll();
    }
});
```

In your DatabaseAdapter which is dboperations in your case

```
public boolean deleteAll() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_TABLE1);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_TABLE2);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Do i need to make a new java class other then my mainActivity in order to start activity when the button is clicked?

Comment: Your activity should extend SQLiteOpenHelper and implement its method.

Comment: In dboperations.java use the code i provided. you can call this method from another activity

Comment: You are most likely correct, but i'd need a bullet point step by step on how where and what to put

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button Login, Register, Delete;
int status = 0;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
 private GoogleApiClient client;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
    Register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Reg);
    Delete  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondelete);


    Register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,          RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View v) {

                                  }

                                  public void DeleteDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, String table) {


                                      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "standing_table");
                                      db.close();
                                  }
```

Comment: Then...public void addStanding (View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent( MainActivity.this,SaveInfo.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void displayStandings(View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent( MainActivity.this,DisplayStandings.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }